# Laravel Livewire Route Binding functionality, similar to Query String?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In my app, I have a library route that accesses all Media models in the "media" table. We can search, filter & sort the media library.

Media can also be grouped into collections via a many-to-many relationship in a LibraryCollection model.

I have a single page within my app that can view both the full library and the library collections. Currently, I am using the query string, but would ideally like to be using route binding as below:

```
// A media library (base URL)
www.example.com/library

// Show recent items
www.example.com/library?filter=recent (current)
www.example.com/library/recent (preferred)

// Show library items in collection 1
www.example.com/library?collection=1 (current)
www.example.com/library-collection/1 (preferred)
```

Using Laravel route binding is cleaner for the user and works more in line with Laravel convention for accessing models i.e. ([www.example.com/library-collection/1](http://www.example.com/library-collection/1))

However, I need to be able to switch between the full library and library collections without reloading the page.

I tried writing my own push-history / replace-history methods, but this is a bit messy and `$queryString` handles it so well that it seems the same to do this.

At the moment, I am using the query string, but I would love to be able to use route binding in the same way, with all URL switching and history states managed by livewire.

Is this currently possible using queryString, or will it be possible in V3?

Edit: to give some context.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Livewire, as far as I know, cannot manage url paths within the same, already loaded component as the path is used when the component is initialised and this is unlikely to change with V3 (I may be wrong on this one).

That being said, you could load the same component in a blade view on multiple  paths or set it up as a full page component on multiple paths, like so:

```php
Route::get('library/recent', \App\Http\Livewire\Library::class);
Route::get('library-collection/{collection}', \App\Http\Livewire\Library::class);
```

and in said component you could use the mount method to retrieve the collection, like so:

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\LibraryCollection;
use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{
    public function mount($collection = null)
    {
        // when /library/recent is called, the $collection variable will be null
        // when /library-collection/1 is called, the $collection variable will have a value 1
    }
}
```

It is important to note, that route model binding isn't going to work in a setup like this so you cannot modify the definition of the `mount` method to something like this

```
public function mount(?LibraryCollection $collection = null)
```

because your `/library/recent` route would not work anymore (it would return a 404).

However you can achieve the same effect by adding something like this to the `mount` method

```php
if (false === is_null($collection)) {
    $collection = LibraryCollection::findOrFail($collection)
}
```

Now, granted, any data you had will be lost when the path changes, not much you can do there and you aren't going to get the nice SPA-like feel to the app as changing the path (as opposed to just a query string) will result in a full page load, but you can leverage turbolinks to return that feeling.